# There is a way to intercept a submit with HTMLFormElement like I can do with XMLHttpRequest using only Javascript?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I find this code that let me intercept `XMLHttpRequest`

```
    (function (open) {
        XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function (method, url, async, user, pass) {
            this.addEventListener("readystatechange", function () {
                if (this.readyState == 4) {
                console.log(this.status);
                }
            }, false);
        open.call(this, method, url, async, user, pass);
        this.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Token 123")
        };
    })(XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open);
```

There is a way to make the same with `HTMLFormElement` in pure javascript?

Comment: Just set up a `submit` event handler for your `form` element.

Comment: there is no way to add an event to every form through prototype. You can look at event delegation with submit on the body of a page.